# Combine two (or more) FileInfo lists...

Tags: c#, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I have something similar to this:

```
var d1 = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(source, @"bills_save." + dt));
var d2 = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(source, @"reports_save." + dt));

var f1 = d1.GetFiles();
var f2 = d2.GetFiles();
```

I want to get, and combine, all the filenames into one FileInfo list. Would make my parsing a lot easier. Concat, AddRange, join... nothing seems to work. Most of what I see is for adding 2 lists, arrays.

Comment: since GetFiles returns an array of FileInfo instances, I'd think examples detailing how to combine two arrays would be what you need.  "Nothing seems to work" isn't enough info.  Give us an example and the error message you get.  This is trivial with, say, Linq:  `var joined = f1.Union(f2);` (edit:  did Join when I meant to do Union, sorry)

Comment: I tried a few different things. Wasn't sure exactly to put in there, so I did go a little sparse on details but both answers (so far) seem to be spot-on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `Concat` certainly should work:

```
// f3 will be IEnumerable<FileInfo>
var f3 = f1.Concat(f2);
```

If you need an array or a list, call `ToArray` or `ToList` appropriately:

```
var list3 = f1.Concat(f2).ToList();
var array3 = f1.Concat(f2).ToArray();
```

By the way, your verbatim string literal doesn't need to be verbatim - it doesn't contain anything which would need escaping.

Comment: I think I must have had a type or something earlier... I thought I tried this, but now it seems to be working.

Comment: about the Verbatim String... I had it done via string math initially (source + @"\subfolder") but stumbled across Path.Combine which is much more graceful :)

Comment: not sure what version of C# if that even what is meant.  But I get FileInfo does not contain a definition of 'Concat'.

Comment: @RobertKoernke: `f1` and `f2` aren't of type `FileInfo`. The return type of `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` is `FileInfo[]`. This is just LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a `List<FileInfo>`, like this:

```
List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
files.AddRange(d1.GetFiles());
files.AddRange(d2.GetFiles());
```

If you have a collection of `DirectoryInfo`s, you can call `SelectMany`:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = directories.SelectMany(d => d.GetFiles());
```

Comment: Good thoughts to ponder. Still trying to wrap my head around LINQ. I like the SelectMany.

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
public static FileInfo[] GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
    {
        string[] searchPatterns = searchPattern.Split('|');
        FileInfo[] fileinfos=null;
        foreach (string sp in searchPatterns)
        {
            FileInfo[] newFiles = dir.GetFiles(sp, searchOption);
            if (fileinfos == null)
            {
                fileinfos = newFiles;
            }
            else
            {
                if (newFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    fileinfos = (FileInfo[])fileinfos.Concat(newFiles).ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return fileinfos;
    }
```

Comment: There is already a perfect answer, that solves OP's problem. Your answer is in the total wrong spot and redundant. Furthermore you dont explain yourself at all, please have a look at [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).